# jqplot individual pointLabels

Tags: javascript, jqplot

I'd like to set different pointLabel settings for each bar, so if a value is small like 1, it will show location: 'e' instead of location: 'w'.  I'm trying the following...

```
series: [{pointLabels: {show: true, location: 'e'}},
         {pointLabels: {show: true, location: 'w'}}]
```

just as a test, but it doesn't seem to work.  Should I remove the seriesDefaults block?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work fine the way you try it. Do not worry about the `seriesDefaults` its setting get overwritten by those in `series`. [Here is the code sample presenting it working.](http://jsfiddle.net/Boro/CxsXk/18/) In the sample the four of the chart labels are set to show in different locations.

*If you still have the issue please build a sample presenting the problem, for example, at http://jsfiddle.net so we can see it.*

Comment: We decided to just increase the pad and keep them on the right outside the bars.  I may use this on our stacked bar though.  What's the usual practice for small values, just let them disappear?

Comment: I think so you should assume some threshold after which you will not display a value this is for example used in pie chart. Also provide a tooltip so a user can see what is the exact value (if the threshold is greater then 1).

Comment: I may have the point labels move to the left side of the bar on our stacked charts, it's on a mobile device so I can't have the usual tool tips.

Comment: Ok, how do you get the value to disappear if the top section is very small?  Say the bottom is 40 and the top of the stack is 3.  It doesn't seem to be edgeTolerance.  I can't use show: false because they hides all the values for that series.

Comment: @Jason this could be a very good new question as I do not know an answer for this particular one. I think you could write a `jQuery` script for this is everything else fails. By as I am saying it is worth to try setting up a new question as others might know better then me. Well technically it is part of this problem but speaking out of experience you will have better luck with a very precise question.